# Computing degree of a map

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, projective-geometry, projective-space

Define $f:\mathbb{CP}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^1$ by
$$f([z_0,z_1])=[p(z_0,z_1),z_1^n],$$
where $p(z_0,z_1)=z_0^n+c_{n-1}z_0^{n-1}z_1+ \dots c_1z_0 z_1^{n-1}+c_0 z_1^n$ is an arbitrary homogeneous polynomial. I would like to compute the degree of $f$. I think I need to use the following: for a regular point $x \in \mathbb{CP}^1$, the differential $df_x:T_x\mathbb{CP}^1 \rightarrow T_{f(x)}\mathbb{CP}^1$ is orientation preserving.

 I am not entirely sure how to show this. I know that $df_x$ is orientation preserving if its Jacobian is positive. However, can I compute it in charts? For instance, in the chart $U_0=\{[z_0,z_1] \mid z_0 \neq 0\}=\{[1,z] \mid z\in \mathbb{C}\}$, we have
$$f([1,z])=[p(1,z),z^n],$$
whose Jacobian is $0$.

Comment: No, the Jacobian is not zero. Work in the obvious chart.

Comment: So if I use the chart $\{[z,1] \mid z\in \mathbb{C}\}$, then I get
$$f([z,1])=[p(z,1),1])=[z^n+c_{n-1}z^{n-1}+ \dots c_1z +c_0,1].$$
I think I am confused about how to compute the Jacobian for homogeneous coordinates. The partial derivatives of the second component are both $0$. But obviously I am not seeing something.

Comment: Work this out for a holomorphic function $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations may be helpful.

Comment: I think I see it now and I can manage to show f is orientation-preserving. How can I use this to compute its degree?

Comment: How many points are in the preimage of a regular value?

Comment: Is it $1$? I am not sure.

Comment: No, I think it's $n$, since a complex polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ roots.

Comment: There you go. ….

Comment: Why do you think people named "degree" the degree ?

Comment: Let $f:\bf C\to   C$ defined by $f(z)=\lambda z$ where $\lambda =a+ib$. What is the determinant of $f$ as a $\bf R$ linear map.